# How to configure JMeter for SSH tunneling over a different host

Tags: ssh, jmeter

i have trouble setting up a JMeter client to connect to a remote JMeter server over an intermediate jumphost.

Especially which ports need to be open and forwarded to which host and how to configure JMeter for that. Apparently there are some blog posts about similar setups but neither describes the ports in detail nor do the connect over an external host (all use localhost?).

The setups is:

JMeter GUI(client) <-> Jumphost <-> JMeter Server

I need to setup one or more SSH Tunnels on the Jumphost and tell the Client and server to connect to this host.

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[http://rolfje.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/distributed-jmeter-through-vpn-and-ssl/](http://goo.gl/8uGdh)

Here I see ports in the article:

> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1099 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1099 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

### **Tried with Java 8**

### 1. Client - modify `jmeter.properties` file adding:

```
remote_hosts=127.0.0.1:55511
client.rmi.localport=55512
```

### 2. Server - modify `jmeter.properties` file adding:

```
server_port=55511
server.rmi.localhostname=127.0.0.1
server.rmi.localport=55511
```

### 3. Connect to the server using:

- Linux and Mac users

  `ssh solr@server -L 55511:127.0.0.1:55511 -R 55512:127.0.0.1:55512`
- Windows users

  `putty.exe -ssh user@server -L 55511:127.0.0.1:55511 -R 55512:127.0.0.1:55512`

### 4. Server - start jmeter

```
cd apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/
./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

### 5. Client - start jmeter

```
cd apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/
./jmeter.sh -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -t test.jmx
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create different remote_host using different local_ports:

CLI - Create tunnels

### Linux

ssh -L 2222:JMeter_server.com:5555 user@server_jump.com

### Windows

putty.exe -L 2222:JMeter_server.com:5555 user@server_jump.com

-L local_port:server_remote:service_port

### The setups is:

JMeter GUI(client) <-> Jumphost <-> JMeter Server

Localhost <-> server_jump.com <-> JMeter_server.com

### Configure client Jmeter

extesion:/localhost:2222/[parameter]